# image slide show with both automated and manual controls

Tags: javascript, css

The code runs quite well, the only issue i'm experiencing is that it doesn't start until its initiated with the control button. I need it to start sliding as soon as the page is loaded, I think it has to do with the display but i'm not quite sure. Kindly go through my code below and correct as appropriate i'll go to the stars and back to make sacrifices for the pandemic to be over if I get a solution

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

showSlides();

function showSlides() {    
    var i;    
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}

function currentSlide(no) {
    var i;    
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex = no;
    slides[no-1].style.display = "block";
}

function plusSlides(n) {
  var newslideIndex = slideIndex + n;
  if(newslideIndex < 4 && newslideIndex > 0){
     currentSlide(newslideIndex);
  }
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}

            /* Slideshow container */
            .slideshow-container {
              max-width: 1000px;
              position: relative;
              margin: auto;
            }
            
            .mySlides {
                display: none;
            }
            
            /* Next & previous buttons */
            .prev, .next {
              cursor: pointer;
              position: absolute;
              top: 50%;
              width: auto;
              margin-top: -22px;
              padding: 16px;
              color: white;
              font-weight: bold;
              font-size: 18px;
              transition: 0.6s ease;
              border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
            }
            
            /* Position the "next button" to the right */
            .next {
              right: 0;
              border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
            }
            
            /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
            .prev:hover, .next:hover {
              background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            }
            
            /* Caption text */
            .text {
              color: #f2f2f2;
              font-size: 15px;
              padding: 8px 12px;
              position: absolute;
              bottom: 8px;
              width: 100%;
              text-align: center;
            }
            
            /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
            .numbertext {
              color: #f2f2f2;
              font-size: 12px;
              padding: 8px 12px;
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
            }
            
            /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
            .dot {
              cursor:pointer;
              height: 13px;
              width: 13px;
              margin: 0 2px;
              background-color: #bbb;
              border-radius: 50%;
              display: inline-block;
              transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
            }
            
            .active, .dot:hover {
              background-color: #717171;
            }
            
            /* Fading animation */
            .fade {
              -webkit-animation-name: fade;
              -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
              animation-name: fade;
              animation-duration: 1.5s;
            }
            
            @-webkit-keyframes fade {
              from {display: block;} 
              to {margin: 0;}
            }
            
            @keyframes fade {
             from {opacity: .4} 
              to {opacity: 1}
            }
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
            <div style="width:100%;background-color: yellow;height:50px;"> </div>
            <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
         <div style="width:100%;background-color: black;height: 50px; "> </div>
            <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
         <div style="width:100%;background-color: blue;height: 50px;"> </div>
            <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
          </div>
        
          <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
          <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
        </div>
        <br>
        
        <div style="text-align:center">
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
        </div>
```

Comment: It is starting without clicking any button https://codepen.io/sandeshsapkota/pen/YzyaNxE

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out

Comment: It won't still start till i click